# Select mailbox "sent mail" or "all mail" in Ruby Net::IMAP

Tags: ruby, gmail, imap

I'm trying to use Net::IMAP in Ruby to search all mail sent by me, but I'm having trouble selecting anything other than INBOX.

```
imap.select('INBOX')
```

works fine, but

```
imap.select('Mail/sent-mail')
```

as shown on the Net::IMAP documentation gives me "Unknown Mailbox".

Incidentally, this is to be used with gmail.

I also tried adding "in", "anywhere" to my imap.search(), but that didn't parse.

Current code:

```
imap.select('INBOX')
now = Time.now.localtime - 1209600 #two weeks
since = now.day.to_s() + "-" + Date::MONTHNAMES[now.month] + "-" + now.year.to_s()
puts "since"
puts since
begin
  mail_ids = imap.search(["FROM", "me", "SINCE", since])
  mail_ids.each do |id|
    text = imap.fetch(id, 'BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]').to_s.split("{").second.chop
    puts text
  end
end
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The "sent mail" folder will differ from provider to provider.  Gmail's "sent mail" folder is named "`[Gmail]/Sent Mail`".  Select that instead and it'll work.

```
imap.select('[Gmail]/Sent Mail')
```

FYI, Gmail's system folders are the following:

- `INBOX`
- `[Gmail]/All Mail`
- `[Gmail]/Drafts`
- `[Gmail]/Sent Mail`
- `[Gmail]/Spam`
- `[Gmail]/Starred`
- `[Gmail]/Trash`

Comment: Note that these folder names are localized.  You can use the XLIST command to get the folder type.

Comment: Beautiful, have been looking for this all over the place, thanks you! How can I select All Mail regardless of the language then?

Comment: Issue an `XLIST "" *` command and select the one that comes back tagged with `\AllMail`.

Comment: This list of system folders worked for me in Perl as well.  Thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can find the names of all folders with:

```
imap.list('*', '*')
```

The Gmail folders name's will change depending on the user selected language. So in Spanish for example:

"[Gmail]/All" Mail will be "[Gmail]/Todos"

Comment: Beautiful, have been looking for this all over the place, thanks you! How can I select All Mail regardless of the language then?

Comment: How about `imap_cli.list('', '*').select { |k| k[:attr].include?(:All) }.first`?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following to be helpful (ruby 2.0.0-p195)

```
# list all folders
imap.list '', '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LIST "" *`. You many end up with thousands of mailboxes. Use   `LIST "" %` . If you are only interested in `children/subfolders`, you can do something like `imap.list '', '%/%'` and so on `imap.list '', '%/%/%'`

lists parent(s) folder only, depth 1.

```
C: RUBY0002 LIST "" "%"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Calendar
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Contacts
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Deleted Items"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Drafts
S: * LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "/" INBOX
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Journal
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk E-Mail"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Notes
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Outbox
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent Items"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Tasks
S: RUBY0002 OK LIST completed.
```

list children . depth 2.

```
C: RUBY0003 LIST "" "%/%"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX/subfolder
S: RUBY0003 OK LIST completed.
C: RUBY0004 SELECT INBOX/subfolder
S: * 2 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 37286] UIDVALIDITY value
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 6] The next unique identifier value
S: RUBY0004 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
```