# IMAP Selecting multi-worded mailboxes

Tags: c#, imap

I am trying to create my own Imap Library on C#, and so far I have been able to do about everything I have tried (connect, login, list, select, fetch, etc).

I am having problems, however, in selecting a mailbox that has multiple words in its name.

For example, the mailbox name "New Label" cannot be selected whereas "INBOX" is successfully selected.

```
0002 LIST "" "%"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "New"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "New Label"
* LIST (\HasChildren \Noselect) "/" "[Gmail]"
0002 OK Success

0003 SELECT INBOX
0003 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)

0004 SELECT New Label
0004 BAD Could not parse command
```

The IMAP specification ([RFC 3501 5.1 Mailbox Naming](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1)) does not reference how this should be treated. It does mention internation naming 5.1.3, but it states that the US-ASCII printable characters represent themselves.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186788/select-mailbox-sent-mail-or-all-mail-in-ruby-netimap) shows that the mailbox name should be sent with the space in it, but this is obviously not working in my case.

This is the code that I am using to create the command (which works fine with every command I have tried so far):

```
    public ResponseStatusEnum sendCommandReceiveResponse(out List<String> responseArray, string command, params string[] cmdParams)
    {
        ResponseStatusEnum response;
        if (command == null) throw new Exception("No command passed in to send to the server");
        // Increment the id before getting the id string
        m_nCommandId++;
        StringBuilder sbCommand = new StringBuilder(CommandId + " ");

        // Include the Imap command
        sbCommand.Append(command);

        //Include the parameters specific to the command
        for (int i = 0; i < cmdParams.Length; i++)
        {
            sbCommand.Append(" " + cmdParams[i]);
        }
        sbCommand.Append(ImapEol);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 3501 does specify that, the first line of page 87 specifies that astring syntax is to be used. Astring is used for a lot of things in IMAP, and in this case it's just:

```
0004 SELECT "New label"
```

Do read the astring/string/nstring/literal productions in the syntax, you have to get them right in order to parse or generate IMAP beyond the hello-world stage. Or use a library if you want to outsource it, there are fine libraries on C#.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to read the syntax section too before asking more questions. I am doing very basic things (and I want to get familiar with IMAP), so I decided to not go for a library.

Comment: I thought you might be doing something like that. You may find the source code of Mailkit interesting to read too, it's C# and well written.

Comment: Fwiw, the source code for MailKit can be found at https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit